# How to parallelize a grouped mutate/summarise in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, grouping, summarization

In tidy R, how do I parallelize a grouped `summarize` (or `mutate`) function call?
A transform to the `iris` dataset illustrates my problem.

I created a simple function - it takes two numerical vectors as args.  It returns a list with a 2-column tibble.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 geoMaxMean <- function(pLen, pWid){
    list(
      tibble(maxLen = max(pLen), 
             geoMean = sqrt(max(pLen) * max(pWid))))}
```

Applying this to iris

```
 gIris <- iris %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(Cols2 = geoMaxMean(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% 
    unnest(Cols2)
```

Gives the intended result.

```
Species     maxLen      geoMean
setosa      1.9         1.067708
versicolor  5.1         3.029851
virginica   6.9         4.153312
```

How do I parallelize the `geoMaxMean` call?  I've tried to rework the call with `lappply` or `foreach` but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm running R 3.4.4 on RStudio Pro.

Comment: The only thing meant to work directly within the tidyverse for parallel processing that I know of is [multidplyr](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr) but I don't think it's under terribly active development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a chunk of code to get that done using the `pbmcapply` package. The `mcapply` package would also work just fine, and would function the same way, but this way you get a progress bar, which is handy.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(pbmcapply)

allSpecies <- 
  iris %>%
  pull(Species) %>%
  unique 

geoMaxMean <- 
  function(species, data){
    data <- data[data$Species == species,]
    pLen <- data$Petal.Length
    pWid <-  data$Petal.Width
    rm(data)

    out <- 
      tibble(maxLen = max(pLen), 
             geoMean = sqrt(max(pLen) * max(pWid))
             )
    return(out)
}

nCores <- 
  detectCores() %>%
  subtract(2)

gIris <-
  allSpecies %>%
  as.list %>%
  pbmclapply(geoMaxMean,
             data = iris,
             mc.cores = nCores
             ) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  tibble("Species" = allSpecies, .)
```

The key difference here is that you have to rethink what goes into the function you're feeding into the parallelized `apply` function. Your original snippet of code assigned all the calculations to a function, and then tried to group everything afterwards. If you design your function to split the data into a subgroup, then perform your calculation, it is very easy to parallelize by using a list of all grouping labels as the input list into `pbmclapply`, and simply supply your data as an argument to the function, rather than the input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, Graeme. I'm trying to implement this approach on my real problems now.

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with `dplyr::group_nest`, `future`, and `furrr:future_map_dfr`.

*(In case it matters, I'm using `dplyr` 1.0.7, `furrr` 0.2.3, `tidyr` 1.1.2, and `future` 1.21.0)*

First, you use `group_nest` to put groups together before splitting for parallelization (e.g. by `worker_id` as below). Then you run on each of the separated worker groups, and `future_map_dfr` automatically recombines into a `tibble` or `dataframe` (e.g. equivalent of running `bind_rows` at the end):

```
library(tidyverse)

geoMaxMean <- function(pLen, pWid) {
  list(
    tibble(maxLen = max(pLen), 
           geoMean = sqrt(max(pLen) * max(pWid))))
  }

n_workers <- 4
# Setup parallelization
future::plan(future::multisession, workers=n_workers)

gIris <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Cols2 = geoMaxMean(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% 
  unnest(Cols2)

gIris_parallel <- iris %>% 
  group_nest(Species, .key="grouped_data") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(.worker_id = sample(1:n_workers, replace=T, size=nrow(.))) %>% 
  dplyr::group_split(.worker_id, .keep=F) %>% 
  furrr::future_map_dfr(
    function(.data) tidyr::unnest(.data, grouped_data) %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      summarise(Cols2 = geoMaxMean(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% 
      unnest(Cols2)
  )
```

As an aside, note that running `summarise` on a function that returns a tibble automatically unpacks the columns, and eliminates the need for dummy variable `Col2`:

```
geoMaxMean_to_tibble <- function(pLen, pWid) {
    tibble(maxLen = max(pLen), 
           geoMean = sqrt(max(pLen) * max(pWid)))
  }

gIris <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(geoMaxMean_to_tibble(Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
  # No need to call unnest
```